# Retrieve size of background image after scaling with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following simple code to get me the background-image dimensions, but it grabs the size of the original image, not the scaled one I have in my div. I want to get pixel dimensions after scaling, is there any way to do that?

```
var actualImage = new Image();
actualImage.src = $("#chBox").css('background-image').replace(/"/g, "").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
actualImage.onload = function () {
    width = this.width;
    height = this.height;
}
```

EDIT:

The CSS to scale the background-image:

```
#chBox {
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;

background-image: url(../content/frog/1.jpg);
background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: contain; /*for webKit*/
    -moz-background-size: contain; /*Mozilla*/
    -o-background-size: contain; /*opera*/
    background-size: contain; /*generic*/

}
```

Comment: I might be missing something here, but if the image is scaled to the width of the element, why not just get the width of the element? $("#chBox").width()

Comment: The div containing the bg image is bigger than the image

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the dimensions of the actual image, you need to get the `$('#someImage').css('width')` and `$('#someImage').css('height')` of the image you want.

edit:

```
#someImage img {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
<td id="image">
    <img id="someImage" src="image.jpg">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert($('#someImage').css('width'));
    </script>
</td>
```

the code above would alert "100px". and of course if you use some jQuery to change the width of the image, like `$('#someImage').css('width','300px')`, the code would the update and alert "300px"

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me. Could you clear up that identifier for me? is img#someImage more like #someImage?

Comment: `img` is just a tag that jQuery uses to identify more clearly what the selector is. however the `img` is not necessary, `#someImage` will work just fine.

Comment: Ah thanks, but I'm trying to find the width of a background image in a div, and not the original size, but the scaled size.

Comment: so the background image is being scaled? how? i must not understand your question. could you please provide some more code or information about your question to help me understand better

Comment: I have a div with a background-image property that is being changed in jQuery (switching images on click). The div size itself is constrained by the parent element, and the background-size property is set to 'contain' so that it gets scaled to the size of the div. I want to lay over some descriptions on top of the images, but I want the description div to be only as wide as the image in the div, which is a background image that is being scaled.

Comment: so the div's background-image gets loaded and then scaled. how is it being scaled(keeping the original ratios or set to fill the entire width and height of the div)? and then you are trying to get the width of the background image?

Comment: It keeps the original ratios, and yes then I am trying to get that adjusted width (and height). Thanks for your persistence in helping me!

Comment: can you please send me the code that you are using to scale the background image

Comment: Added it to my post under EDIT

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13120/discussion-between-noah-passalacqua-and-prismspecs)

Answer (score 0):

The code is doing what you're telling it to do. I don't believe there is a way to grab the 'scaled' size.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks to everyone for their responses but I thought of a bit of a workaround. I would like to see this feature in a later release of jQuery (grabbing scaled width, height) but with some math, it ain't so bad.
Essentially,

```
            // create a fake image and load the original from background-img src
        var actualImage = new Image();
        actualImage.src = $("#chBox").css('background-image').replace(/"/g,"").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
        actualImage.onload = function() {
            // get original values
            var origWidth = this.width;
            var origHeight = this.height;
            var width = 0;
            var height = 0;
            // need to bump it 140px as it seems the div's left comes from the super-container
            var bump = 140;
            // if the image is fat rather than tall,
            if(origWidth > origHeight){
                // set width for description to width of bg-img container
                var width = $("#chBox").width();
                // set left
                $(".description").css("left", bump);
                // calculate height and set bottom
                height = (width * origHeight) / origWidth;
                var blankSpace = $("#chBox").height() - height;
                $(".description").css("bottom", (blankSpace/2));


            } else {
                // if image is tall,
                var height = $("#chBox").height();
                // calculate width
                width = (height * origWidth) / origHeight;
                // set left
                var setLeft = $("#chBox").width();
                $(".description").css("left", (setLeft/2) - 58);    //wtf, 58?
                // set bottom to 0
                $(".description").css("bottom", 0)
            }

            $(".description").width(width);
        }
```

There's quite a bit of site-specific stuff there, but basically I ran some algebra to find the proportions of the image. If it's a fat image rather than a tall image, the width of the container is the scaled width. The height is equal to the scaled width * original image height divided by the original image width. For some reason (and if someone could help with this I'd be grateful) the margin: 0 auto; property of my CSS doesn't work when you change up the div width, so I had to manually center it.